# Test file upload Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to test file uploading by REST API. I found it quite confusing to send file as `RequestParam` instead of `RequestBody`.

Controller method:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public
@ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(
        @RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
        @RequestParam(name = "path") String path) {
    logger.debug("File upload REST requested");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(fileService.uploadFile(
            multipartFile, path),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

1.Now I would like to test it and I've used mocks. While debugging it, I see that mock service working but method exactly with this arguments is not invoked, so the test if failed. How could I handle this?

```
@Test
public void testUploadFile() throws Exception {
    String mockName = "mock";
    MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(mockName, mockName.getBytes());

    when(mockFileService.uploadFile(mockMultipartFile, rootDir)).thenReturn("success");

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/files/upload")
            .file("file", mockMultipartFile.getBytes())
            .param("path", rootDir))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("success"));

    verify(mockFileService, times(1)).updateFile(mockMultipartFile, rootDir);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockFileService);
}
```

2.How could I test this with Postman? I see that I can send file in Body, but how could I send it as param?

**EDIT:**

I've changed the method, but the problem is not there:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
mockFileService.uploadFile(
org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile@61bd0845,
"/"
);
```

Looks like method are using 2 instances of MockMultipartFile. And the second question is still open, how could this method be tested from Postman?

Comment: you have mocked actual call to method you want to test, I believe you only wanted to mock file?

Comment: @freakman I read that it's not good to mock a file. Here I want to mock service in order not to really upload file, so no, I wanted to mock real method call

Comment: but you have mocked file, mocked service, so what do you want to test here? This is testing nothing at the moment :) My first guess why this fails is that mockMvc knows nothing about mockFileService and trying to run some real method. You can print some more details with adding 'andDo(print())'

Comment: Can you provide the complete class code of testUploadFile() ? I wanted to check which runner u are using PowerMock or SpringJUnit4 ?

Comment: @freakman I think he is right, he is testing REST url endpoints are configured or not, not the actual service or file content

Comment: @quento Check my answer, if that resolves your issue

Comment: @javaguy exactly, I am testing only REST

Comment: @quento did you have look at my answer ? Did it work ?

Comment: @javaguy, i made edit, please check

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the test case fails, because 
the problem is in your test case at the end, you are verifying the call to `updateFile`() which is incorrect as in your `controller` you are using `uploadFile`(), you MUST use the same method to `verify`.

So, you need to change the `verify` line as below:

```
verify(mockFileService, times(1)). uploadFile(mockMultipartFile, rootDir);
```

In other words, Mockito verify validates the number of times a method is invoked as you are trying to `verify` the call on a different method (not being used in controller), it is failing.